# How to reset the prefereceManager.java file

Tags: java, android

I just started Android programming and I am a beginner in coding. At first I got this error

```
`'getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)' is deprecated.`
```

And by going to the source part, getDefaultSharedPreferences was not there and a notification appeared on the top of the page and I downloaded it and

```
`public static SharedPreferences getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context) {
         return context.getSharedPreferences(getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(context),
                 getDefaultSharedPreferencesMode());
     }`
```

It was added, but after this, the prefereceManager.java file got an error. There are 54 errors that I don't know what to do.
Please guide me how to return the prefereceManager.java file to its original state

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the initial thing you saw was a warning, not an error.  When a function is deprecated, that means that it's not suggested to use anymore and may not work properly.  If you look at the documentation, it will generally tell you what to use instead.  The documentation is here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager

In this case, as of Android SDK version 29, the entire PreferenceManager class is deprecated.  Instead, you're directed to use the androidx implementation.  What happened is Google decided to take a bunch of classes that were part of the SDK but not core OS functionality and remove it from the SDK, into a separate library.  That made it easier to push updates to it, as updating the SDK requires an OS update and not just a library update.  The implementation remains the same, you just need to use the androidx version.  See https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/settings for examples.

So you have two options, and either will really work:

1)Port to use AndroidX PreferencesManager.  This is the preferred option.

2)Ignore the warning and use the old stuff anyway.  It will continue to work for likely several years, but it may not receive updates that go into the androidx version, unless there's a security concern.